# How to display message in r?

Tags: r, if-statement

i have a dataframe which displays false (please see below) based on certain conditions. I would like to display a message (say, fail) if 'false' appears in all the cells

```
    a   b   c
1   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
2   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
3   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

i tried the code below, but it doesn't work

```
if (dataframe_name=="false")
print(fail)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to consider. I've included it to (1) show you the "`message`" function, (2) show you how to create a minimal reproducible example, (3) how to write a simple function, and (4) provide a working answer to your question since the existing answer is incorrect.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(FALSE, FALSE), b = c(FALSE, FALSE))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c(FALSE, TRUE), b = c(FALSE, FALSE))

checkMe <- function(inDF) {
  if(!any(inDF == TRUE)) message("false") 
  else message(paste0((sum(inDF == TRUE)/prod(dim(inDF)))*100, "% true values"))
  inDF
}

checkMe(df1)
# false
#       a     b
# 1 FALSE FALSE
# 2 FALSE FALSE
checkMe(df2)
# 25% true values
#       a     b
# 1 FALSE FALSE
# 2  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
if(dataframe_name == FALSE)
    print("fail")
```

`"FALSE"` is a string. `FALSE` is a boolean value.

Comment: You might also want to include `all` to check if all the values are `FALSE`. Right now, probably only the first value will be checked in the `if` statement with a warning.

Comment: on including **all** **if all (dataframe_name == FALSE)**, i get a message _[1] "fail"_does it mean it checked all the values or [1] indicates it checked just the first value?

Comment: @user2926956 Can you update your question with more relevant code?