# Linking data frame to message box

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame as:

```
Name         category  
A             sales_1    
B             sales_2  
C             sales_3
```

How to get 'category' value if I enter 'Name' values in message box?

e.g  If I enter Name value as 'A' then it should display 'sales_1' as category and same as B&C

Comment: We will need a bit more information. What is the message box? What is your code?

Comment: To subset based on name, try: `df1[ df1$Name == "A", "category" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo=function(df){
  x <- readline("Enter Name!\n(press enter to continue)")
  return(df[df$Name==x,df$category])
}
```

also see

[How to display message in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628369/how-to-display-message-in-r)